# Switch statement won't restart after termination

Tags: c, switch-statement, embedded, avr

I am struggling with exiting from the following switch statement. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have several case statements and my problem is if the break flag goes up high from an external interrupt, any operation should be stopped and go back to its initial state waiting for start flag to go up high.

Currently all described functions are working except for going back to its initial state after break flag is high. For example, operation gets terminated when I press cancel. However, the system won't start again after cancellation.

Thanks in advance.

```
while(1)
{   

    switch(state)
    {
        case STOPPED:   // Master control
            if(start_flag == true)
            {
                state = WAITING_FOR_SYNC;
                start_flag = false;
            }
            break;

        case WAITING_FOR_SYNC:
            if(sync_flag == true)   // waiting for input to be synchronised
            {
                state = SAMPLED_AND_PROCESSING;
                sync_flag = false;
                sampleCounter = 0;
                samplingComplete = false;
            }
            break;

        case SAMPLED_AND_PROCESSING:    
            if(samplingComplete == true) // samples to be loaded in a buffer
            {   
                gpio_set_pin_low(AVR32_PIN_PA07);
                windowing();
                rms(x);
                fft_run(window);
                peak_search(fft_mag);
                envelope_output(envelope);
                state = LOOP;
            }
            break;

        case LOOP:
            gpio_set_pin_high(AVR32_PIN_PA07);
            delay_ms(5);
            loop++;
            if(loop == 23)
            {
                state = RS485_OUT;
                loop=0;
            }
            else
            {
                state = SAMPLED_AND_PROCESSING;
                sampleCounter = 0;
                samplingComplete = false;
            }
            break;

        case RS485_OUT:
            //SendTx();
            state = STOPPED;
            break;
       }
    } // switch statement close bracket
    if(break_flag == true)
      state = STOPPED;
}// while close bracket
```

Comment: Show declaration of `break_flag`.  Is it `volatile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that `break_flag` remains true and stops the operation from restarting properly. When you process `start_flag`, you set it to false after setting the state to WAITING_FOR_SYNC:

```
if(start_flag == true)
{
     state = WAITING_FOR_SYNC;
     start_flag = false;
}
```

so apply the same logic to `break_flag`:

```
if(break_flag == true)
{
    state = STOPPED;
    break_flag = false;
}
```

This way `break_flag` will only be applied once and you won't have to clear it before restarting.

Answer (score 0):

The check for break_flag == true is outside the while loop.
So once inside the while loop, the program is never going to check
for the break_flag one way or another.  My guess without seeing the rest of the code is that the break_flag check should be inside the while loop just after the switch.  A break statement inside a switch breaks out of the
switch statement, not any surrounding loop.

Comment: Hi, sorry my presentation is wrong, the if statement is actually inside the while loop. Its just after the switch statement close bracket.

Comment: As per chux's comment then, how is break_flag declared here?  If it's not volatile the compiler might be optimizing out the check.  Nothing in the while loop changes break_flag, so the compiler could move the check outside the loop and then generate constant code.

Comment: @user464502  What is initialized value of `break_flag` ?